# View and Synonym hirarchy oracle

Tags: view, synonyms

The Dba of our company has created views for the tables for all the users.
We have 230 users, he has created 230 views for each tables!
I want to replace this by public synonym and grant select to the users.
Example:
Create public synonym emp to scott.emp
grant select on scott.emp to public;
When I query synony after droping view it works. 
Without dropping the view If I query emp oracle does the select on the view.
When we have a view and synony in the same name, what is the hirarchy between this?
Is there a workaround for this problem.
Because when I modify a table I have to correct 230 view scripts!

Answer (score 1):

The resolution order is described in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561):

> Oracle Database attempts to qualify the first piece of the name
>   referenced in the SQL statement. For example, in scott.emp, scott is
>   the first piece. If there is only one piece, the one piece is
>   considered the first piece.
>
> **A)** In the current schema, the database searches for an object whose name
>   matches the first piece of the object name. If it does not find such
>   an object, it continues with step b.
>
> **B)** The database searches for a public synonym that matches the first
>   piece of the name. If it does not find one, it continues with step c.
>
> **C)** The database searches for a schema whose name matches the first piece
>   of the object name. If it finds one, it returns to step b, now using
>   the second piece of the name as the object to find in the qualified
>   schema. If the second piece does not correspond to an object in the
>   previously qualified schema or there is not a second piece, the
>   database returns an error.
>
> If no schema is found in step c, the object cannot be qualified and
>   the database returns an error.